# script\cli steps to add a mounted snapshot to failover cluster for SQL server

Tags: sql-server, failovercluster

I know the following setups

1. use cluster resource and create a physical disk
2. Assign Disk Signature
3. Add dependency of SQL of the new disk
4. bring the disk online

I am not sure if these are the right setups. Can you let me know how to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

The steps probably look more like this.

1. Rescan the SCSI bus.
2. Bring the new disk online
3. Add the disk as a clustered resource
4. Add dependency of SQL to the new disk
5. Attach the database to the SQL Server instance

This can all be scripted between diskpart.exe cluster.exe and sqlcmd.exe.

Comment: Do you have any reference around around using cluster.exe and Sqlcmd.exe?